# Issue with lowpass image filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, dft, lowpass-filter

I need to apply a simple low-pass filter on an image, however this needs to be done in the frequency domain. However the final result is a very noisy image, suggesting that my process is incorrect somewhere.

My track of thought has been

1) Center the image (Testpatt) and apply a 2D FFT

```
tpa1 = size(Testpatt, 1); tpa2 = size(Testpatt, 2);
dTestpatt = double(Testpatt);


for i = 1:tpa1
    for j = 1:tpa2

        dTestpatt(i,j) = (dTestpatt(i,j))*(-1)^(i + j);
    end
end

fftdTestpatt = fft2(dTestpatt);
```

2) Generate the low-pass filter and multiply it with the Fourier transformed image (Note: the low pass filter needs to be a circle of 1's within the radius Do)

```
lowpfilter = zeros(tpa1, tpa2);
Do = 120;

for i = 1:tpa1
    for j = 1:tpa2


       if sqrt((i - tpa1/2)^2 + (j - tpa2/2)^2) <= Do
           lowpfilter(i,j) = 1;
       end

   end
end


filteredmultip = lowpfilter*fftdTestpatt;
```

3) Take the real components of the inverse 2D FFT and revert the centering.

```
filteredimagecent = real(ifft2(filteredmultip));


for i = 1:tpa1
    for j = 1:tpa2

        filteredimage(i,j) = (filteredimagecent(i,j))*(-1)^(i + j);
    end
end
```

Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add the image (or a similar) ?

Comment: Any image will do really, the effect should be that of an easily recognizable blurring effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm surprised why this didn't give you an error, but you are performing **matrix multiplication**, not element-wise multiplication in the frequency domain.  Recall that filtering in the frequency domain requires element-wise multiplication of the two transformed signals to perform the equivalent covnvolution operation in spatial domain.  You simply need to change the multiplication statement so that it is the element-wise equivalent:

```
filteredmultip = lowpfilter.*fftdTestpatt;
```

Also, make sure you convert your image back to the same data type as the original image before display.  If your image was `uint8` for example, you'll want to use `im2uint8` to convert it.  This is important primarily for display purposes and for writing images to file. If you left it as `double` as you've done in your code, showing the image would be visualized as mostly white because displaying images of type double assumes the range of values is from `[0,1]`.

As a side note, I suspect the reason why you aren't getting an error is because your image and filter are square, so the dimensions when it comes to matrix multiplication are valid.  If you decide to do this on non-square images, you will definitely get an error.

## Warning - Use of an ideal lowpass filter

What you are implementing is filtering with an **ideal** lowpass filter, so what will happen is that you will see ringing effects when you lowpass filter.  The reason why is because this comes straight from signal processing theory.  It requires a large (or rather infinite...) number of sinusoids in the spatial domain to realize a hard edge in the frequency domain. Remember that the FFT is a decomposition of your signal in terms of sinusoids. When you use this lowpass filter to filter your image, this is visualized as ringing in the reconstructed image as hard edges need a large summation of sinusoids (hence the fact the ringing) to create them.

To show you these effects, let's demonstrate for an example image.  I'm going to use the cameraman image that's part of the image processing toolbox.  If I used a radius of `Do = 40` and ran your code (corrected), this is the original image and this is what I get after filtering:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, that's pretty bad.  The ringing comes from the hard edges of your filter in the frequency domain.  People tend to use a more gradual decrease in magnitude as you move farther away from the centre.  A good example is a **Gaussian blur**.  What you would do instead is define a standard deviation and then create a mask that is the same size as your image that represents a 2D Gaussian.

Recall that the 2D Gaussian can be represented as:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur)</sup>

You simply loop over all pixel coordinates and compute the above equation.  I didn't multiply by the scaling factor in the front as you really don't need to do it.  As such, you can use this code to generate a Gaussian mask, which is equivalent to what you have with your two `for` loops but doing it more vectorized.  I define a grid of 2D coordinates that span the same size as your image, then run through the equation for each location in the image.  We of course need to **centre** the kernel so you must offset by the middle of the image as you have done with your previous lowpass filtering code.  I've also decided to use your `Do` variable as the standard deviation.

```
Do = 40;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:tpa2, 1:tpa1);
lowpfilter = exp(-((X - (tpa2/2)).^2 + (Y - (tpa1/2)).^2) / (2*Do*Do));
```

So we now get this as the filter response:

[image]

... and when I filter, I get:

[image]

Compare with the original image:

[image]

As you can see, the blur is much better.  No ringing.  As such, when you filter images, make sure you avoid hard edges in the filter as this will produce ringing artifacts in the spatial domain.

## Some more suggestions

I have a few more suggestions to give you to make this code run fast.

### Avoid using loops to centre the image

As you already know from signal processing theory, if you pre-multiply the pixel values in the image by `(-1)^(i+j)` where `(i,j)` is a spatial location of the pixel you want to filter, this centres your image in the frequency domain. I would actually avoid using loops to do this and take the FFT first **then** centre the image.  You can use a function called [`fftshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) that performs the centering for you.  First take the FFT of your image, then invoke this function after:

```
fftdTestpatt = fft2(dTestpatt);
fftdTestpatt = fftshift(fftdTestpatt); % Centre the FFT
```

### Avoid using loops for generating the filter

I would also avoid using loops to generate your filter.  Specifically, for your code with the ideal filter, replace your code with this which follows the same logic as what I had with the Gaussian filter.  We can also remove the `sqrt` operation and make sure that you're comparing with the squared of the radius to avoid any unnecessary computation:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:tpa2, 1:tpa1);
lowpfilter = (X - tpa1/2).^2 + (Y - tpa2/2).^2 <= Do^2;
lowpfilter = double(lowpfilter);
```

Take special care of the element-wise power operation (`.^`) in the above code.  The last statement is important as we need to cast the result back to `double` as generating the filter first would in fact give you a `logical` type as the result. We need the `double` type to ensure the precision of the FFT is respected.

### Avoid loops to uncentre the image after filtering

After you're finished filtering, you again multiply by `(-1)^(i+j)` to uncentre the image.  Use the related [`ifftshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifftshift.html) function to uncentre the image after you filter with the FFT:

```
filteredmultip = ifftshift(filteredmultip); % Uncentre first
filteredimage = real(ifft2(filteredmultip));
```

Comment: Oh dear, I was unaware of the technicality, especially since I wasn't getting an error.


The resulting filtered image is a great improvement, with the original being very recognizable.

Unfortunately I am unconvinced that the code is giving me the exact result I need, I'll comb over it and check it out.


Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rallad No problem.  Actually you're implementing an **ideal** low-pass filter.  I'm adding some more results with a Gaussian blur.

Comment: @Rallad Have a look. You get better results if you choose the filter properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the added information! 

Yes you're right, it is an ideal filter. I'll read up on it as soon as I get back to the problem. The help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Rallad No problem :) I've added more information on why you see the ringing.  It goes back to Signal Processing theory.  Let me know if you need any more help.  Good luck!

Comment: Converting the image back to unassigned 8 bit from double did the trick! I really need to catch up on these little details. Thanks for the suggestion, I would have never figured out what was going wrong!


Also I've went through all of what you've posted, I'll try implementing some variations! Hopefully, it'll be a much more straightforward process now that the core-coding is in place. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yup! I agree. It's simply just a matter of changing the filter. Also, yes converting back to the original data type is important. It's primarily for display purposes and for writing images to file. If you left it as double, showing the image would be visualized as mostly white because displaying images of type double assumes the range of values is from [0,1] so values larger than 1 saturate to white. I'll put that explanation in my answer later. Also, don't be shy to ask about details. Filtering in frequency domain requires a lot of small steps to get right. Good luck!

Comment: @Rallad I've added some more edits to my post... specifically, I have some tips for you to make your code fast.  The code works on its own, but if you have high resolution images, this will be very slow... especially because of the loops. I've provided some alternatives to your code that do the same thing but avoid loops all together.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Perfect! Everything is working like a charm. It was only mean to be a fundamental exercise. I'll definitely go over all your suggestions! Thanks! :)